# scala only classes can have declared but undefined members

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
  def random[T](array: Array[(T, Double)]): T = {
    var total: Double = 0
    array.foreach(x => total += x._2)

    if (total > 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The total ratio shouldn't greater than 1.")

    val ratio = rand.nextDouble()
    var min: Double = 0
    var max: Double = 0

    var theOne:T = null // error here !!!

    array.foreach {
      x =>
        max += x._2
        if (ratio > min && ratio <= max)
          theOne = x._1

        min += x._2
    }

    theOne
  }
```

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to do `null.asInstanceOf[T]`. If you want better answers (namely answers which describe how to improve your code which is really ugly) you should describe what you want to do. Currently your code doesn't make much sense because `ratio > min` can never be true but for the very first element.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it's really ugly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Option** type:

```
  def random[T](array: Array[(T, Double)]): Option[T] = {
var total: Double = 0
array.foreach(x => total += x._2)

if (total > 1)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("The total ratio shouldn't greater than 1.")

val ratio = rand.nextDouble()
var min: Double = 0
var max: Double = 0

var theOne:Option[T] = None

array.foreach {
  x =>
    max += x._2
    if (ratio > min && ratio <= max)
      theOne = Some(x._1)

    min += ratio
}

theOne
}
```

with **match expression**

```
def show[T](x: Option[T]) = x match {
 case Some(s) => s
 case None => null
}

val res = random...
show(res)
```

Comment: You can use `res getOrElse null` instead of `match`.

Comment: @Ben Kyrlach You can't assign **var theOne:T = _**, because its local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you've provided no guarantee that null is a valid value for the type T. Scala's type hierarchy starts like this.

Any

AnyVal extends Any  //cannot be null

AnyRef extends Any  //can be null

Because you haven't constrained the type T in any way, it has no guarantee that T isn't a subclass of anyval (like Int or Double), and therefor cannot allow you to assign null. A simple solution is to replace null with _ like so...

```
class Container[T] {
    var t: T = _
}
```

This will make the Scala compiler replace the _ with an appropriate default value for T (null for reference types).

Comment: var theOne:T = _  still fail the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Ich you want to have fast code, don't use `foreach`. Otherwise you can do the following to draw proportional to the second tuple element:

```
def random[T](array: Array[(T, Double)]): T = {
  val cumulative = array.scanLeft(0d)(_ + _._2)
  val pick = rand.nextDouble() * cumulative.last

  array.
var min: Double = 0
var max: Double = 0

var theOne:T = null // error here !!!

array.foreach {
  x =>
    max += x._2
    if (ratio > min && ratio <= max)
      theOne = x._1

    min += ratio
}

theOne
```

}